# Delete a set of lines in Vim text editor on Mac

Tags: vim, text-editor

I know the command to delete lines are, for example:

```
1,100d
```

to delete the first 100 lines. But how and where should I execute this commmand. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Esc (you'll be taken to the command mode), then

```
:1,100d Enter
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. If your question has been answered, please accept the answer.